# disabling trailing slash is messing up the url

Tags: .htaccess

I am working on a local website on my Mac (OSX 10.11.3) using AMPPS.  I made a `.htaccess` file in the root directory of the website, located at `/Applications/AMPPS/www`.  Here is the contents of the file

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
DirectorySlash Off
```

I'm not 100% sure what line 1 does, but it's for lines 4-5. I added line 3 to try to fix my issue but it didn't help (I'll explain the issue down below).  And line 6 seems to be where the problem lies.  I added it because I do not need relative urls, and I want the url to look a bit cleaner.

Whenever I go to `localhost/asf`, it stays without a trailing slash (just as I want it).  But if I add a trailing slash, `localhost/asf/`, the url gets redirected to `localhost/Applications/AMPPS/www/asf`, where `/Applications/AMPPS/www/asf` is the location of `asf` relative to the root directory of my computer.

Also note, when I tried this using "foo" instead of "asf", the url didn't redirect at all.  Meaning `localhost/foo/` stays as is, no change at all.

This could be a Mac or AMPPS issue, but does anyone have a solution to at least the first issue I have (the redirect to the root directory of my computer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have turned the `DirectorySlash Off` meaning that your existent dirs are now accessible with or without the trailing slash.

The issue that you are facing now is that your "existent dires" if you request them with a trailing slash  they are getting rewritten to the `/index.html`

To avoid this behaviour, you need to exclude your real directories from the rule using the following RewriteCond :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

With this `RewriteCondition`
 , you can connect to your dirs with or without a slash at the end  **/dir** or
 **/dir/**

```
 DirectorySlash Off
 Options -MultiViews
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Comment: is there any way to force a redirect from **/dir/** to **/dir** ?

Comment: @Jaketr00 To redirect **/dir/** to **/dir** you can use :

`DirectorySlash off

RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R]`


take note of the char **-d** it means if existing dir, then redirect /dir/ to /dir.

Comment: I have also just noticed that using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` helps with a few issues.